# Image Loading by keystrokes in Python with pygame

Tags: python, image, keyboard, pygame

Im trying to make a simple image gallery which loads images with keystrokes using pygame in python, and this is how far i got

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
width=1366;
height=768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height ), pygame.NOFRAME)
pygame.display.set_caption('Katso')
penguin = pygame.image.load("download.png").convert()
mickey = pygame.image.load("mickey.jpg").convert()

x = 0; # x coordnate of image
y = 0; # y coordinate of image

*keys = pygame.event.get()
for event in keys:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            screen.blit(mickey,(x,y)); pygame.display.update()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            screen.blit(penguin,(x,y)); pygame.display.update()*

running = True
while (running): # loop listening for end of game
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
#loop over, quit pygame

pygame.quit()
```

i expect to press the arrow keys to load certain images

the screen opens but no image gets loaded

Comment: use only one `for event` loop - inside `while running`. First `for event` will not wait for your  key press. It will go directly to `while running` which doesn't check keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Program never wait for keypress so you have to check keys inside `while` loop.

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE)

WIDTH = 1366
HEIGHT = 768

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.NOFRAME)
pygame.display.set_caption('Katso')

# - objects -   

penguin = pygame.image.load("download.png").convert()
mickey = pygame.image.load("mickey.jpg").convert()

x = 0 # x coordnate of image
y = 0 # y coordinate of image

# - mainloop - 

running = True

while running: # loop listening for end of game
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                #screen.fill( (0, 0, 0) )
                screen.blit(mickey,(x,y))
                pygame.display.update()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                #screen.fill( (0, 0, 0) )
                screen.blit(penguin,(x,y))
                pygame.display.update()

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks i missed that while loop fixed it